# Return only repeated elements from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, matrix

I have an array of "N" `Objets`, what I need to do is to recover or keep only those `Objets` in the same array or another where the value of the key `newField` is in common with all `Objects` of the `Array`. Note: the new `Array` or the final `Array` must only have one Object per repeated element. 
Note 2: I had to edit this because the return value it must be common in all Objects. For example, if theres 3/3 objects with the same newField it will return one, if 2/3 Objects with the same newField it wont return anything

This is what I have but it's really nothing... :/

(this is a filter from Angular 2)
I'll be appreciated for any kind of help.

Thank you

```
    export class BucketPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public arr = []
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.seleccion(value);
  }

  seleccion(value)  {
    console.log("val: " +JSON.stringify(value))
    var newValue = new Array()
      for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < value[i].length; y++)  {
          if(value[i][y])  {
            var val = value[i][y]
            do {
              newValue.push(value[i][y])
              val = value[i][y]
            } while (value[i][y].newField !== val.newField)
          }
        }
      }
      return this.filter(newValue)
  }

  filter(values)  {
    var field: string[] = new Array()
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)  {
      Object.keys(values[i]).map((obj,key)  =>  {
        if(values[i].newField == values[i][obj]) field.push(values[i])
        })
    }
    this.arr = field
    var result = [];
      this.arr.forEach((subArr, index) => {
        if(this.validate(subArr, index))
          result.push(subArr);
    });

    console.log("Result: ",result)
  }

  validate(subArr, index) {
      var test = true;
      for(var i = 0; i < subArr.length && test; i++){
          var obj = subArr[i];
          var subtest = false;
          for(var j = 0; j < this.arr.length && !subtest; j++){
              if(index == j) continue;
              var found = this.arr[j].find(function(e){
                  return e["newField"] == obj["newField"];
              });
              if(found) subtest = true;
          }
          test = test && subtest;
      }
      return test;
  }
}
```

This is an example of the Array:

```
 [[{"id":42,
    "idBucket":"patrimonial",
    "originalField":"c",
    "newField":"nCliente",
    "name":"Número Cliente",
    "description":"Número del Cliente",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1},{"id":43,
    "idBucket":"patrimonial",
    "originalField":"ct",
    "newField":"nContrato",
    "name":"Número Contrato",
    "description":"Número de Contrato",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1},{"id":45,
    "idBucket":"patrimonial",
    "originalField":"s",
    "newField":"sucursal",
    "name":"Sucursal",
    "description":"Sucursal",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1
    },{"id":47,
    "idBucket":"patrimonial",
    "originalField":"sp",
    "newField":"sProducto",
    "name":"Subproducto",
    "description":"Subproducto",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1
    }],
    [{
    "id":11,
    "idBucket":"expunic",
    "originalField":"nc",
    "newField":"nCliente",
    "name":"Número Cliente",
    "description":"Número del Cliente",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1
    },{
    "id":12,
    "idBucket":"expunic",
    "originalField":"t",
    "newField":"titulo",
    "name":"Título Aplicación",
    "description":"Título de la Aplicación o Gaveta",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1
    }],
    [{
    "id":16,
    "idBucket":"bastanteo",
    "originalField":"t",
    "newField":"titulo",
    "name":"Título Aplicación",
    "description":"Nombre de la Gaveta",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1
    }]]
```

In this example will return nothing because the common `newField` value is "titulo" but it is only in Array position 1 and 2 but not in 0, if newField value "titulo" is in all 3 it will return a new Array with just one Object , doesnt care wich one of the 3.

another example

```
 [[{
    "id":11,
    "idBucket":"expunic",
    "originalField":"nc",
    "newField":"nCliente",
    "name":"Número Cliente",
    "description":"Número del Cliente",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1
    },{
    "id":12,
    "idBucket":"expunic",
    "originalField":"t",
    "newField":"titulo",
    "name":"Título Aplicación",
    "description":"Título de la Aplicación o Gaveta",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1
    }],
    [{
    "id":16,
    "idBucket":"bastanteo",
    "originalField":"t",
    "newField":"titulo",
    "name":"Título Aplicación",
    "description":"Nombre de la Gaveta",
    "filter":true,
    "visible":true,
    "idDataType":1
    }]]
```

In this example it will return one `Object` because in all 2 Objects it haves the same value for `newField`, does't care wich one of both. Although if the array has 10 Objets in all 10 `Objects` must be the same `newField` value. Note if can be more than 2 `Objects` to return only if there are 2 `newFields` values in common in all `Objects`

Comment: Post an example of the structure of the array and what would be the desired result of that example.

Comment: I just edited the post with the example of the array @ibrahimmahrir and I want for example a new Array of Objects only if the newField repeats in all original Objects

Comment: So, in this example, the new array will contain just the objects with the IDs 12 and 16. Right?

Comment: No, because 12 and 16 is "titulo" but "titulo" is only in Array positions 1 and 2, not in 0 @ibrahimmahrir  This example return nothing, but instead if "titulo" is in all 3 Objects will return only one Object in a new Array. :)

Comment: what would be the result for this array. Post the desired output (no need to post everything just the an array containing the IDs will suffice). With explanation if possible (explain why an element is in the resulting array)

Comment: I just edited again the post, hope it will helps. The Output only must be the Object or Objects that haves the same newField in common in all Objects. The Object to be in the new Array could be anyone of those, It doesn't need to be different kind of Object.

Comment: So if every object in the array has the same value for *newField* it should return one object, even if that value doesn't appear in any other array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach:

```
function getFirstObjectForEachRepeatedKey(values, keyName)
{
  if (!keyName)
    keyName = "newField";

  var haveSeenKey = {};
  var alreadySelectedValue = {};
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
  {
    var key = values[i][keyName];

    if (!(key in haveSeenKey))
      haveSeenKey[key] = values[i];
    else
    {
      var selectedValue = haveSeenKey[key];

      if (selectedValue !== alreadySelectedValue)
      {
        result.push(selectedValue);
        haveSeenKey[key] = alreadySelectedValue;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice Thank You!!!, that code works, but I forgot something, the repeated element must be in all the Objects, could you do that change, please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking for a function that returns the first object if *all* the objects have the same key, otherwise returns nothing??

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand. (I tested it with your array and gave the right results):

```
// define your array here (must be named arr or you can modify the code accordingly
var arr = [[{}, {}, {}], [{}], [{}, {}]]; // ...

function validate(subArr, index){
    var test = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < subArr.length && test; i++){
        var obj = subArr[i];
        var subtest = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < arr.length && !subtest; j++){
            if(index == j) continue;
            var found = arr[j].find(function(e){
                return e["newField"] == obj["newField"];
            });
            if(found) subtest = true;
        }
        test = test && subtest;
    }
    return test;
}

var result = [];
arr.forEach(function(subArr, index){
    if(validate(subArr, index))
        result.push(subArr);
});
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
var arr = [[{
        "id": 42,
        "idBucket": "patrimonial",
        "originalField": "c",
        "newField": "nCliente",
        "name": "Número Cliente",
        "description": "Número del Cliente",
        "filter": true,
        "visible": true,
        "idDataType": 1
    }, {
        "id": 43,
        "idBucket": "patrimonial",
        "originalField": "ct",
        "newField": "nContrato",
        "name": "Número Contrato",
        "description": "Número de Contrato",
        "filter": true,
        "visible": true,
        "idDataType": 1
    }, {
        "id": 45,
        "idBucket": "patrimonial",
        "originalField": "s",
        "newField": "sucursal",
        "name": "Sucursal",
        "description": "Sucursal",
        "filter": true,
        "visible": true,
        "idDataType": 1
    }, {
        "id": 47,
        "idBucket": "patrimonial",
        "originalField": "sp",
        "newField": "sProducto",
        "name": "Subproducto",
        "description": "Subproducto",
        "filter": true,
        "visible": true,
        "idDataType": 1
    }],
    [{
        "id": 11,
        "idBucket": "expunic",
        "originalField": "nc",
        "newField": "nCliente",
        "name": "Número Cliente",
        "description": "Número del Cliente",
        "filter": true,
        "visible": true,
        "idDataType": 1
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "idBucket": "expunic",
        "originalField": "t",
        "newField": "titulo",
        "name": "Título Aplicación",
        "description": "Título de la Aplicación o Gaveta",
        "filter": true,
        "visible": true,
        "idDataType": 1
    }],
    [{
        "id": 16,
        "idBucket": "bastanteo",
        "originalField": "t",
        "newField": "titulo",
        "name": "Título Aplicación",
        "description": "Nombre de la Gaveta",
        "filter": true,
        "visible": true,
        "idDataType": 1
    }]];

function validate(subArr, index){
    var test = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < subArr.length && test; i++){
        var obj = subArr[i];
        var subtest = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < arr.length && !subtest; j++){
            if(index == j) continue;
            var found = arr[j].find(function(e){
                return e["newField"] == obj["newField"];
            });
            if(found) subtest = true;
        }
        test = test && subtest;
    }
    return test;
}

var result = [];
arr.forEach(function(subArr, index){
    if(validate(subArr, index))
        result.push(subArr);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I just updated my code with yours and theres no errors but it return the same array with the same Objects. :( Can you tell me if I implemented right?

Comment: @CanKerDiAlike the result is stored in the `result` array not in the `arr` itself. `console.log(result);` logs the correct answer.

Comment: yeah if you check the code I'm console.log the "result" and it's giving me the same.

Comment: check the line with console.log ```("Result: ",result)```

Comment: you do `this.arr = field` are you sure `field` is like the array you posted in the exampe.

Comment: @CanKerDiAlike is `field` like the data you posted or not?

Comment: You should post your code as a runnable snippet with test data. You should also explain your algorithm, i.e. how the code works.

Comment: @CanKerDiAlike check the code snippet It prints the correct answer. There is something wrong with your impementation I think.